# Automation FindFirst on TreeScope does not find element

Tags: automationelement

I have a problem with TreeScope finding an element in Internet Explorer when searching the Name property and ControlType property.

mainElement is the AutomationElement representing "internet Explorer_Server.

all automation elements are listed under mainElement in UISpy.

public Auto.AutomationElement GetElementByNameAndControlType(Auto.AutomationElement mainElement, System.Windows.Automation.ControlType controlType, string propertyName)

{

```
  Auto.AutomationElement target = null;

  Auto.PropertyCondition typeCondition1 = new Auto.PropertyCondition  (Auto.AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, controlType);

   Auto.PropertyCondition typeCondition2 = new Auto.PropertyCondition(Auto.AutomationElement.NameProperty, propertyName);

   Auto.AndCondition andCondition2 = new Auto.AndCondition(typeCondition1, typeCondition2);

   target = mainElement.FindFirst(Auto.TreeScope.Descendants, andCondition2);

        return target;
    }
```

I was finally able to find the element with the code below, but really want to understand why the code above didn't work.

public Auto.AutomationElement GetElementByIsValuePatternAvailablePropertyAndName(Auto.AutomationElement mainElement, string name, Auto.ControlType controlType)

{

```
   Auto.AutomationElement target = null;

   Auto.Condition conditions = new Auto.AndCondition(new Auto.PropertyCondition(Auto.AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true),

   new Auto.PropertyCondition(Auto.AutomationElement.IsValuePatternAvailableProperty, true));

   // Find all children that match the specified conditions.
    Auto.AutomationElementCollection elementCollection = mainElement.FindAll  (Auto.TreeScope.Descendants, conditions);

  foreach (Auto.AutomationElement ae in elementCollection)
  {
      if (ae.Current.Name == name)
      {
                target = ae;
                break;
       }
  }

  return target;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Please add assembly references of UIAutomationClient and UIAutomationTypes in your project ;-)
[via martin's answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/62819228-740a-4fa8-8367-14da77cc84b9/missing-using?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation)